# How can i select records from two tables in cake php(cake 2)

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I am new to cake php . i have two tables

1. ce_landing
2. ce_stat

structure is

ce_stat

```
id       keyword       click
1        keyword1       24
2        keyword2       2
3        keyword3       6
```

ce_landing

```
id       page_keyword
1        keyword1,check,keyword3
2        keyword2,usa,alphanumeric
```

i want to fetch all the records `ce_landing.page_keyword` is present in `ce_stat.keyword`. I am using this in my cake php model

```
 public $hasMany = array(
        'Stat' => array(
            'className' => 'Stat',
            'foreignKey' => 'keywor',
            'dependent' => false,
            'conditions' => array('Stat.keyword LIKE' => '%Landing.page_keywords%'),
            'group' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'exclusive' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'counterQuery' => ''
        )
        );
```

but this is generated sql query like

> SQL Query: SELECT `Stat`.`id`, `Stat`.`customer_id`, `Stat`.`account`,
>   `Stat`.`campaign_id`, `Stat`.`campaign`, `Stat`.`keyword`,
>   `Stat`.`ad_grp_id`, `Stat`.`ad_grp`, `Stat`.`impressions`,
>   `Stat`.`clicks`, `Stat`.`cost`, `Stat`.`qualityScore`,
>   `Stat`.`keywordState`, `Stat`.`date_from`, `Stat`.`date_to`,
>   `Stat`.`user_id`, `Stat`.`created`, `Stat`.`modified`, `Stat`.`keywor`
>   FROM `EB_adwords`.`ce_stats` AS `Stat` WHERE `Stat`.`keyword` LIKE
>   '%Landing.page_keywords%' AND `Stat`.`keyword` =
>   ('559f479a-82ac-4e3d-8c24-19b5c0a8011f')

so it returns null data because of AND `Stat`.`keyword` =('559f479a-82ac-4e3d-8c24-19b5c0a8011f') conditions.

**Update**

what i want to get all the records from `ce_landing` with total clicks according to keywords present . i.e for record 1 in `ce_landing`. i'll get the result

```
id       page_keyword                     clicks
    1        keyword1,check,keyword3        30
    2        keyword2,usa,alphanumeric       2
```

Comment: I think it will need custom query using `UNION`

Comment: not possible with cake relation model ??

Comment: union is not working ' "The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns " is the error

Comment: Because you need to have equal number of columns

Comment: Just use `SELECT field1, field2 from table1 UNION ALL SELECT field1, field2 from table2` where fields are the ones you need

Comment: What SQL statement do you want Cakephp to run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You needs a SQL statement equivalent to:

```
SELECT ce_landing.id, ce_landing.page_keyword, SUM(ce_stat.click) AS total_clicks
FROM ce_landing
LEFT JOIN ce_stat
 ON FIND_IN_SET(keyword,page_keyword)>0
GROUP BY ce_landing.id, ce_landing.page_keyword;
```

which does not easily translate to Cakephp's `find` method.  Just use the [query method](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#model-query) to implement.

```
$this->Landing->query("SELECT Landing.id, Landing.page_keyword, SUM(ce_stat.click) AS total_clicks
    FROM ce_landing AS Landing
    LEFT JOIN ce_stat
     ON FIND_IN_SET(keyword,page_keyword)>0
    GROUP BY Landing.id, Landing.page_keyword;");
```